# error on cell value change event in vbnet datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I simply added message box and when i run the form the message box keeps popping up until all the rows have finish loaded n gridview.

My initial plan was to show a message that you have edited the cell. So does cell change event happens when the gridview is being loaded and extracting the rows from the database or when you change the value of cell.
How to stop the message box from popping out countless of times and whether or not i am using the wrong event?? Below is exactly what i did. I am also using datasource to get my records from the database

```
Private Sub grdDataGrid_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdDataGrid.CellValueChanged


    MsgBox("You have edited the follwing cell")


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the messageBox from popping out countless times:

```
Private Sub grdDataGrid_DataBindingComplete(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs) Handles grdDataGrid.DataBindingComplete

MessageBox("your message")

End Sub
```

When you use the _CellValueChanged event- all of the cells that are being loaded with data are being changed when you render the gridView. So each cell is firing the _CellValueChanged event

Comment: defined databound is it the data set or the adapter ?? sorry i am still new to this and the even you stated on what conditions does it occur

Comment: I am sorry you are developing a windows form application, I gave you the code for ASP.NET. I have edited my response. I believe you want to display the message on DataBindingComplete, after the value of a cell has been changed and bound to the grid.

Comment: Yes i tired cellEndEdit and it works how ever if it is a combobox and after i selected the value cellEndEdit only fires after i left the cell. If there an event which occurs while editing. Because the event only works after i confirm editing.  This is an extra question i have accepted your answer btw.

Comment: You would need to use an event of the combobox. Another solution could be to use the _CellLeave event of the grid. The _CellLeave event will fire after the cell you edited no longer has focus.

Comment: but is it possible for a combobox inside the gridview to use begin edit or cell focus events?

Comment: Not to sure about window forms, but it looks like there is a Find() method. You would have to create a controls collection, find the control you want then fire the event.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/9160fbd8-4a3c-49ad-a156-108a0c6b8986